# How to search a list of Object by another list of items in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How to search a list of a class object with one of its property matching to any value in another list of strings

I am able to get filtering based on a single string , but not on a list of strings

```
final List<shop_cart.ShoppingCart> cartprd = snapshot.documents
      .map((f) => shop_cart.ShoppingCart.fromMap(f.data))
      .toList();
```

Comment: use `Iterable.where()` method if you want to filter out some items from your original `Iterable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to find unique values between two lists without using a loop in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516833/is-there-any-way-to-find-unique-values-between-two-lists-without-using-a-loop-in)

Comment: Please follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516833/is-there-any-way-to-find-unique-values-between-two-lists-without-using-a-loop-in/59516944#59516944 for anyone who is looking for a solution.

Answer (score 30):

```
  List<SomeClass> list = list to search;
  List<String> matchingList = list of strings that you want to match against;

  list.where((item) => matchingList.contains(item.relevantProperty));
```

If the number of items in `list` is large, you might want to do:

```
  List<SomeClass> list = list to search;
  List<String> matchingList = list of strings that you want to match against;

  final matchingSet = HashSet.from(matchingList);

  list.where((item) => matchingSet.contains(item.relevantProperty));
```

Or else just always store the matching values as a hashset.

Answer (score 28):

**In case if you want to check for a value in a list of objects . you can follow this :**

```
 List rows = [
          {"ags": "01224", "name": "Test-1"},
          {"ags": "01224", "name": "Test-1"},
          {"ags": "22222", "name": "Test-2"},
        ];
    
    bool isDataExist(String value) {
    var data= rows.where((row) => (row["name"].contains(value)));
      if(data.length >=1)
     {
        return true;
     }
    else 
     {
        return false;
     }
    }
```

you can put your own array of objects on **rows** . replace your key with **name** . you can do your work based on true or false which is returned from the function **isDataExist**

Answer (score 4):

As of today, you can't.

(A side note : You can use .where, .singleWhere, .firstWhere. [This](https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2) site explains various list/array methods.)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `List.where()` to filter a list

```
final List<shop_cart.ShoppingCart> cartprd = snapshot.documents
      .where((f) => shop_cart.ShoppingCart.contains(f.data));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var one = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'jay'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'jay11'},
    {'id': 13, 'name': 'jay222'}
  ];

  int newValue = 13;

  print(one
      .where((oldValue) => newValue.toString() == (oldValue['id'].toString())));
```

OUTPUT : **({id: 13, name: jay222})**

store output in any variable check if variable.isEmpty then new value is unique either

```
var checkValue = one
      .where((oldValue) => newValue.toString() == (oldValue['id'].toString()))
      .isEmpty;
  if (checkValue) {
    print('Unique');
  } else {
    print('Not Unique');
  }
```

OUTPUT : **Not Unique**