# Is there any way to find unique values between two lists without using a loop in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to find unique values between two lists without using a loop?

```
List<String> first = ['A','B','C','D']; 
List<String> second = ['B','D'];
```

I need the result to be like this:

```
result = ['A','C'];
```

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884062/how-to-search-a-list-of-object-by-another-list-of-items-in-dart

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `where()` with `contains()` methods from `List`:

```
void main() {
  List<String> first = ['A','B','C','D']; 
  List<String> second = ['B','D'];

  List<String> result = first.where((item) => !second.contains(item)).toList();
  print(result); // [A, C]
}
```

Edit in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/73f7c386cbb7246c617712c390d4dbb1).