# I have two List of Model . How can I get the difference between them?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, difference

```
List a = [

AbsentModel(name: "abir", id: 1),
AbsentModel(name: "fahim", id: 2),
AbsentModel(name: "rahim", id: 3),
AbsentModel(name: "akash", id: 4), ]


List b = [
AbsentModel(name: "akash", id: 4),
AbsentModel(name: "fahim", id: 2),
AbsentModel(name: "rahim", id: 3),]
```

`
**I need the output of -
the difference between List a and List b**

result -

```
`List c = [ AbsentModel(name: "abir", id: 1),];
```

I have tried to toSet() but it only can give me the result If i made all list without model.
Like if made simple id List then it works.
But can not get the difference when I am using model data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to find unique values between two lists without using a loop in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516833/is-there-any-way-to-find-unique-values-between-two-lists-without-using-a-loop-in)

Comment: @OMiShah not actually . I can get the result with single value. But can not make the result when using list of model data.

Comment: IF the below solutions answers your question, please approve it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would work fine as others. You just need to use [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package.

```dart
void main() {
  List a = [

AbsentModel(name: "abir", id: 1),
AbsentModel(name: "fahim", id: 2),
AbsentModel(name: "rahim", id: 3),
AbsentModel(name: "akash", id: 4), ]


List b = [
AbsentModel(name: "akash", id: 4),
AbsentModel(name: "fahim", id: 2),
AbsentModel(name: "rahim", id: 3),]

  List<AbsentModel> c = a.where((item) => !b.contains(item)).toList();
  print(c); 
}
```

However, you need to redefine the `AbsentModel` as follows:

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class AbsentModel extends Equatable {
    final String name;
    final int id;

    AbsentModel({required this.name, required this.id,});

    @override
    List<Object> get props => [name, id];
}
```

> Equatable overrides `==` and `hashCode` for you so you don't have to waste your time writing lots of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct, but does not take into account the fact that the deviating value would not be recognised if it were in list b.

This solution is similar to the above one, but checks the difference from `a` to `b` and from `b` to `a`. Also it is written as an extension for generic `List`, so it can be used for all kind of lists.

```dart
extension Difference<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> difference(List<T> to) {
    final diff = where((item) => !to.contains(item)).toList();
    diff.addAll(to.where((item) => !contains(item)));
    return diff;
  }

main() {
...
  final diff = a.difference(b);
}
```

Also you do not have to use the Equatable package (if you don't want to), since you could overload the `==` operator:

```dart
class AbsentModel {
  final String name;
  final int id;

  AbsentModel({required this.name, required this.id});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return (other is AbsentModel) && other.id == id && other.name == name;
  }
}
```